# Hierarchical python virtualenvs

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

Is it possible to create a hierarchy of python virtualenvs? For example, on an HPC system, imagine that sysadmins install the global python, and library developers create a python virtual environment `venv1`, and app developers create their own virtual environment `venv2`.

Can the app developers source `venv1`, then source `venv2` and then install their preferred dependencies without root access or alteration of the library virtualenv `venv1`?

Naively, I run:

```
~/tmp ❯❯❯ python3.9 -m venv venv1/
~/tmp ❯❯❯ python3.9 -m venv venv2/
~/tmp ❯❯❯ source venv1/bin/activate.fish
(venv1) ~/tmp ❯❯❯ echo $PATH
~/tmp/venv1/bin /usr/local/bin
(venv1) ~/tmp ❯❯❯ source venv2/bin/activate.fish
(venv2) ~/tmp ❯❯❯ echo $PATH
~/venv2/bin /usr/local/bin/
```

which doesn't work. So certainly they cannot be nested without some flags to the environments.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, and ended up solving it with .pth files (which is similar to how development packages work under the hood).

In my case I have a singularity container which requires a specific version of ROCm on the host, so I wanted to be able to fix/make common the tensorflow-rocm and pytorch versions aligned with the ROCm-dkms on the host. So I created a `venv` in my home folder, installed `pytorch`, then made my project folder and put another `venv` in there, and then added `/home/logan/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/` to a new `common.pth` file which I put in `/home/logan/project1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/common.pth`.

So in other words, it looks like this:

```
/home/logan
├── venv
│   └── lib/python3.10/site-packages* (pytorch with ROCm installed here)
└── project1
    └── venv
        └── lib/python3.10/site-packages (project1 pkgs installed here)
            └── common.pth (links to * above)
```

Now it uses the pytorch from the `/home/logan/venv` but installs it's own deps into `/home/logan/project/venv`. This seems to work fine for me, hope it helps someone else! And if there are any better ways I'd be open to hearing about them :)

Answer (score -1):

Once you have a `virtualenv` set up, you can use `pip` to install any packages you like in it. So there's no advantage to sourcing other environments 'directly'.

You can however generate a `requirements.txt` listing the packages installed in an existing environment, then use that to then install them in a new one:

```
venv1/bin/pip freeze >requirements-venv1.txt
venv2/bin/pip install -r requirements-venv1.txt
```

Comment: I think there are cases when venv hierarchy would be useful. My own example: I have venv with jupyterlab + some essential packages. Together it makes 86 packages! I use this venv to perform many small proof of concepts, test ideas, solve small problems. Now I want to play with a single small code using pandas. I certainly do not want to pollute my jupyterlab venv by installing pandas with its dependencies. Replication of the venv seems wasteful. Ideally I would create a sub-ordinate venv for jupyterlab+pandas experiments.